# Favorite Tags Selection Doesn't Match

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching, new-nav

I am trying to make a repro for a question by having no favorite tags, go to the page (`filter:favorite tags`) and refreshing the page. But after deleting my favorite tags and refreshing the page, it seems to still have my favorite tags:

[image]

Seemingly, I have to manually edit the favorite tags section myself to have officially no favorite tags. Can we have the favorite tags on both sides to be the same after refreshing the page please? It is better to have a constant list of favorite tags that matches the group of favorite tags on the right-hand side.

Comment: I added the `new-nav` tag since the left-hand side is only there because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "favorite" is selected, but you actually have no "favorites", we use your top <del>5</del> 6 most used tags.

While I agree is not intuitive, this is because of backwards compatibility with the old nav "`/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags`" behavior.

Comment: But I have six showing on the left side, not five.

Comment: typo, corrected